# Probability with Multiple Sets and Anti Sets

Tags: probability, multisets

Calculate: $P(A \cap B'\cap C')$

Given:

- $P(A) = 0.7$
- $P(B) = 0.8$
- $P(C) = 0.75$
- $P(A \cup B) = 0.85$
- $P(A \cup C) = 0.9$
- $P(B \cup C) = 0.95$
- $P(A \cup B \cup C) = 0.98$

I can upload a pic of my work so far (in which I attempt to break down the formulas to it's elementary forms), but I keep getting to a step which I cannot move on from.

Comment: what are $B'$ and $C'$?

Comment: $ B' = 1 - B $ and such forth for C;

Comment: What event's probability do you think $P(A\cup B)-P(A)$ represents?  What event's probability do you think $P(A \cup B\cup C)-P(A\cup B)$ represents? How might you answer the question?

Comment: @Henry P(A U B) - P(A) = P(B $\cap$ A')

P(A U B U C) - P(A U B) = P(C $\cap$ B' $\cap$ A')

Correct?

Comment: @Henry Thank you so much for the subtle yet ingenious piece of instruction. I think a lesson to take from this is no matter how complicated the problem, an old fashioned ven-diagram approach helps A LOT :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
A\cap B'\cap C'=(A\cup B\cup C) - (B\cup C)
$$

where

$$
B\cup C
\subseteq A\cup B\cup C
$$

Now can you answer by yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Prove $$A \cap B'\cap C' = A \setminus [(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cup B \cup C)] \setminus [(A \cup C) \setminus (A \cup B \cup C)]\setminus (A \cup B \cup C)$$ and use it to find the answer!

Comment: I think I know you from another SE site. Glad to see you on this one also.

Comment: @TomAu pleased to meet you again! :)